# Facing issues in Jmeter script for asmx calls

Tags: jmeter

We recorded a business flow with Jmeter. In our script we have some asmx calls. All calls are sending requests in http format.
The recorded asmx requests are not sending any parameters (not possible to do correlation).
But after replay, all asmx calls are failing where we are sending some session values in cookies in our requests in view result tree. But not
Getting those sessions in any of the previous response.

Please help me out to fix it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is in cookies.

1. Try adding a [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test plan. JMeter should be smart enough to handle cookies for you. If you have any cookies being sent via "Browser-derived Headers" - remove them.
2. If point 1 doesn't help you should be able to manually extract cookie data from `Set-Cookie` header via [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor). Inspect [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) Listener output for any `Set-Cookie` headers being sent in responses.

Don't forget to "tell" your Regular Expression Extractor to look at `Headers` response field (it defaults to `Body`)